# Where on multiple whereHas

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I need to be able to run a where query on a model and multiple of its relations at once. At the moment I am doing it like this, for a single relation

```
$users = $users->whereHas('contacts', function ($query) use ($request) {
    $query->where('name', 'like', '%' . $request->input('filters_search') . '%')
    ->orWhere('contact_name', 'like', '%' . $request->input('filters_search') . '%');
);
```

So this searches my `user.name` and `contact.name` fields for the search input, but I need to be able to search multiple relations, not just `contacts`. Something like this

```
$users = $users->whereHas(['contacts','photos','status'], function ($query) use ($request) {
    $query->where('name', 'like', '%' . $request->input('filters_search') . '%')
    ->orWhere('contact_name', 'like', '%' . $request->input('filters_search') . '%');
);
```

So that I can search through the user, contacts, photos and status tables/relations for the search input.

What is the cleanest/best way to achieve this?

Comment: You have name and contact_name in all of your tables?  How exactly do you expect this to work?  Just if it matches any of them?

Comment: Yes if it matches any of the `orWhere` given. It doesn't have to match them all.

Comment: `So this searches my user.name and contact.name fields for the search input`.  No, it doesn't.  Your first query tries to search contact.name and contact.contact_name.  Nothing is searched on the user table since both your conditionals are inside the whereHas closure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you did happen to be searching the same columns in all of your tables, you could extract the closure to a variable:

```
$closure = function ($query) use ($request) {
    $query->where('name', 'like', '%' . $request->input('filters_search') . '%')
    ->orWhere('contact_name', 'like', '%' . $request->input('filters_search') . '%');
}
```

But you'd still have to independently query each relationship:

```
$users->whereHas('contacts', $closure)
      ->orWhereHas('photos', $closure)
      ->orWhereHas('status', $closure);
```

Comment: I tried this in a closure but I just get errors about the column name not existing in the database

Comment: Then you don't have contact_name and name in those related tables... They would need to exist for this type of query to work, I'm just going based on your question's example.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to structure my question so explain what i need. Basically I need to be able to search through a model and multiple of its relations with a keyword, and if any of them exist, return the primary model.

For example, type into a search bar for a user, and it searches the user, user contacts, use profiles, and if any of them return true, return the user.

Comment: Well, you still have to specify the columns to search.  If you don't have name and contact_name columns on the related table, you can't try to search those columns in the whereHas closure.

Comment: I have the names of the columns I want to search, but the columns do not exist in every table. Each table has different column names so I need to be able to list the column names i want to search.

Comment: Then you need to use different closures instead of the same, but the concept is still the same in my answer of using orWhereHas

Comment: @VikasKatariya awesome.  Those medical doctors and first responders arent the only ones that save lives.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
$users = $users->whereHas('photos','status', function($query) {
    $query->where('name', 'like', '%' . $request->input('filters_search') . '%');
});
$users = $users->whereHas('contacts', function($query) use ($request) {
    $query->where('contact_name', 'like', '%' . $request->input('filters_search') . '%');
});
```

**OR** you should try below way:

```
User::where('name', 'like', '%' . $request->input('filters_search') . '%')
->whereHas('contacts', function($query) use ($request) {
    $query->where('contact_name', 'like', '%' . $request->input('filters_search') . '%');
})
->get();
```